# Unit-test issue in my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having an issue loading a $resource object in my case.

I have something in parent controller like

```
$scope.data = Product.$query();
```

then in the child controller, I have

```
$scope.data.$promise.then(function(product){
     console.log(data);
})
```

My factory

```
angular.module('testApp').factory('Product', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/product');
}]);
```

The reason I put `Product.$query()` in the parent controller is because I want it to be shared and use in different child controller.

My test file is like following

```
describe('Product test ', function () {
    var $httpBackend, childCtrl,  scope;

    beforeEach(module('testApp', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$log', console);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        childCtrl = _$controller_('childCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    describe('some test', function() {
        it('some test here', function(){
             //codes...
        })
    })
});
```

When I run the test, I am getting

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.data.$promise')
```

I am not sure what's going on here. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As your I going to test `$resource` object in jasmine for that you need to create your `$httpBackend` mock response that will return when you do query to `$resource` you shouldn't use `$resource  directly.

```
describe('Product test ', function () {
    var $httpBackend, childCtrl,  scope, Product;

    beforeEach(module('testApp', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$log', console);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, Product) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        Product = Product;

        childCtrl = _$controller_('childCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            Product: Product
        });
    }));

    describe('some test', function() {
        it('some test here', function(){
             $httpBackend.expect('GET', '/api/product').respond([{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' }]);
             childCtrl.data = Product.query();
                 expect(childCtrl.projects).toEqualData([]);
                 $httpBackend.flush(); //flushing $httpBackend
                 expect(childCtrl.data).toEqualData([{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' }]);
        })
    })
});
```

For more details you could refer [**this link**](http://tech.pro/q/57/angularjs-unit-testing-using-jasmine-and-resource-backend)

Comment: I am getting the error after I revised based on your answer.   ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $scope   thanks though and +1

Comment: getting another error.... Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- childCtrl

Comment: @FlyingCat it should as per work http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/13/how-to-unit-test-controllers-in-angularjs-without-setting-your-hair-on-fire/

Comment: I don't have reference error anymore but getting the original error. TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.data.$promise') It is so frustrating

Comment: @FlyingCat did you looked at link which I've added as per that it should clearly work..does `$scope.data = Product.$query();` gets called before accessing promise..you may need to create your own promise..

Comment: Yes I do. I can load the controller just fine because I have another test file that use the same syntax. I think the problem is it doesn't recognize the $scope.data.$promise and I am not sure how to fix it. The link you provide doesn't say much about it. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: because you need somehow generate a promise object into the data.since you are in jasmine you need to create mockHttpBackend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77127/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-flyingcat).